# Getting text options from drop down menu into an array to iterate through in order to navigate to a different page

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I would like to collect all of the options text within a drop down menu so I would be able to iterate through that array. For each option text, I would like to click on that option, then navigate to a different page, and be able to return to the original page to continue down the array.

Essentially it would be like

```
for i in drop_down_menu
    collect option text
    append option text to an array
    for i in array
         choose i
         click button that navigates to different page
         go back to previous page
         i+1
```

I've been trying to figure out how I could get just the text of the options but nothing is working. I imagine that the text ought to be strings within a list.

I have tried to see if I do have an array with is_instance?, type_of?, is_a? (I read somewhere that the latter 2 are the same but I thought it wouldn't hurt to try!) and that failed...When I view the elements inside they aren't strings either.

This is my code thus far:

```
   sel = @driver.find_element(:id, 'txt_source') #This is the drop down menu's id
        all_options = sel.find_elements(:tag_name ,'option') #These are the options

        all_options.each do |option| #iterating through each option with i as option
            puts "Value is: " + option.attribute("text") #Just me checking what I have in the list
            next if option.text == "" #The first option is a blank so I skip it
            option.click #click the option
            @driver.find_element(xpath: '//*[@id="search_button"]/button[2]').click # Button 
            @driver.find_element(xpath: '//*[@id="search_button"]/div/a[3]').click # Another button
            @driver.find_element(xpath: '//*[@id="main_action"]').click # This is the button that navigates to a diff page
            @driver.switch_to.default_content # Switching iframe
            wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 60) # Waiting 
            wait.until {@driver.find_element(:id, 'action_frame')} # Finding iframe
            @driver.switch_to.frame('action_frame') # Outer iframe
            @driver.switch_to.frame('app_display') # iframe I need
            sleep(10) # Sleep to help me see what's going on
            puts "Found the frames" # Note
            @driver.find_element(xpath: '/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input').click # Button for download
            sleep(10) # Viewing
            @driver.switch_to.default_content #Swtich back frames
            @driver.find_element(xpath: '//li[@id="app_sub3"]/a').click # Button that returns me to previous page. It's a tab.
            puts "Clicking for search" # Note
            sleep(10) # View
        end
```

It works until I return to the previous page. Since the page is refreshing, I get the dreaded StaleElement Error.

I expected it to cycle through each option within all_options, navigate to a different page to do some stuff, return back to the original page, and go to the next option to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
drop_list = []

        all_options. each do |e|
           drop_list << e.text
        end
        #puts drop_list
        drop_list.is_a? Array



            drop_list.each do |option|

                next if option == ""
                @driver.find_element(id: 'txt_source').find_element(xpath: "//option[@value='" + option + "']").click
                @driver.find_element(xpath: '//*[@id="search_button"]/button[2]').click
                @driver.find_element(xpath: '//*[@id="search_button"]/div/a[3]').click
                @driver.find_element(xpath: '//*[@id="main_action"]').click
                @driver.switch_to.default_content
                wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 60)
                wait.until{@driver.find_element(:id, 'action_frame')}
                @driver.switch_to.frame('action_frame')
                @driver.switch_to.frame('app_display')
                sleep(10)
                puts "Found the frames"
                @driver.find_element(xpath: '/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input').click
                sleep(10)
                puts "Here the fuck I am"
                @driver.switch_to.default_content
                @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[contains(text(),'Search')]").click
                sleep(10)
                puts "Clicking for search"
                wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
                wait.until{@driver.find_element(:xpath, '//*[@id="action_frame"]')}
                @driver.switch_to.frame(2)
                sleep(10)

            end
```

Helps if you know the syntax.